# Remove (from list) all the items which contains other item - Python

Tags: python, list

I have some list, and I want to remove from it every item which contains other item, except the item itself.

For example:

if my list looking like this:

> ["AAA", "STACK_OVERFLOWAAAAAAA", "123AAAAA45678", "123456", "FOO", "DIR", "ITEM", ........]

Now, I want that the code will remove all the items which includes "AAA" in it.
After that scan I want that the code will remove all the items which includes "123456" in it (if there are), and so on.

The wanted output should be like this:

> lst = ["AAA", "123456", "FOO", "DIR", "ITEM", ........]

This is my code, and from some reason, it doesn't work...

```
lst = ["AAA",
   "STACK_OVERFLOWAAAAAAA",
   "123AAAAA45678",
   "123456",
   "FOO",
   "DIR",
   "ITEM"
   "AAAAA1234",
   "VDFKGMGDFRAAAAAAAAAA",
   "FNHBFDGBNDFGFHFGDUHGDRGJRAAAAAAAAA",
   "6545154DDFEFRGAAAAAAA",
   "123",
   "ABC",
   "abc"]

# The meaning of this variable is to indicate if the sub - item has already found in the list.
# If so, the code should remove all the next items which contains the current sub - item
AlreadyFound = False

# ItemToSearch = the sub - item which the program should search in the other list - items.
for ItemToSearch in lst:

    # Start the loop and search the sub - item in every item which in the list.
    for ItemToCheck in lst:

        # If the current item contains the sub - item..
        if (ItemToSearch in ItemToCheck):

            # If the sub - item has already found in the list
            if (AlreadyFound == True):

                # Delete the current item from the list
                del CurrItem
            else:
                AlreadyFound = True

print "\n".join(lst)
input()
```

I will glad to get some help.
Thank you.

Comment: A bit confused. If you remove everything with 'AAA' in it, then 'STACK_OVERFLOWAAAAAAA' would not exist for the next iteration. Did you mean to say the next iteration would start with '123456'?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Either way the end result would be the same. Anything that might be removed by 'STACK_OVERFLOWAAAAAAA' would be gone since it has 'AAA' as a subset

Comment: @CodeMonkey, You right, of course. I corrected my question.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> lst = ["AAA", "STACK_OVERFLOWAAAAAAA", "123AAAAA45678", "123456", "FOO", "DIR", "ITEM"]
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i+1:] = [y for y in lst[i+1:] if x not in y]
...     
>>> lst
['AAA', '123456', 'FOO', 'DIR', 'ITEM']
>>>
```